Definition of entropy and microstates (Huang)
The definition of Boltzmann entropy given in Ref. 1 appears to be different from most sources I've seen up to this moment. Let me start from the latter: typically textbooks assume that in a given ensemble there is a probability distribution $p_i$ and via using the definition of entropy in microcanonical ensemble:
$$S=-k_B\ln\Omega(E)$$
$\Omega(E)$ number of microstates at energy $E$
(I won't describe it here), infer the form of Gibbs entropy (check e.g. Ref. 3)
$$S=-k_B\sum_i p_i\ln p_i$$
On the other hand, Ref. 1 in eq. $(5.41)$ entropy is defined as
$$S=k_B\ln\Gamma$$
where $\Gamma$ is the occupied volume in phase space.
Now, the problem arises in the next section, namely section $5.8$, in eq. $(5.44)$ of Ref.1 the volume is the sum over all distributions of the number of microstates corresponding to each distribution
$$\Gamma=\sum_{\{n_i\}}\Omega(\{n_i\}). \tag{5.44}$$
Why would they sum over all distributions and why do others get away without doing this?
Then, in the next section they get rid of the sum exploiting the fact that there is a term (exponentially) dominating the sum. Still, despite the final result $(5.52)$ being the same, this is the only reference where I've seen a sum over all distributions even considered. Can you explain this and compare it to Ref.3's approach?
I have checked out the previous edition, Ref. 2, and I think the corresponding section does a better job, so I updated a picture below. The question still remains, though. Why a sum over all distributions? I haven't seen this elsewhere and even in principle I don't understand why one would do that.
Reference

Introduction to Statistical Physics, Kerson Huang. 2nd Edition, CRC Press, 2004.
Introduction to Statistical Physics, Kerson Huang. 1st Edition, Taylor&Francis, 2001. Picture
Tong's notes, eq. (1.30)


Consider to include all relevant equations (at least of reference 1).

I've just updated with the sum I mentioned. Other than that, I don't think there are other equations necessary. That being said, I'd appreciate to have your feedback as to whether it still feels incomplete.

What is eq. 5.48 and 5.49 you mention in your appendix?

@TobiasFünke thank you for your feedback. I'll update that part as soon as I can. Given that it is a side question, I might even decide to remove that appendix.

When they're using $\Gamma$ are they dealing with the microcanonical ensemble? Pay attention that there's some notation abuse in writing $\ln \Gamma$ since $\Gamma$ is not non-dimensional

The units $1/h^3$ are understood, yet not fixed (entropy is defined up to a constant). That being said, the question is about $(5.44)$ and why they would consider summing over distributions
